# Getter/Setter in Flutter using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I am making an app in Flutter and i am using Android studio for that. But it is not making getter and setter by using alt+insert command to generate getter and setter automatically.is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 51):

You don't need that in Dart.

A field is equivalent to a getter/setter pair.
A final field is equivalent to a getter.

You change it only to actual getters/setters if additionally logic is required and this change is non-breaking for users of that class.

Public getter/setter methods for private fields is an anti-pattern in Dart if the getters/setters don't contain additional logic.

```
class Foo {
  String bar; // normal field (getter/setter)
  final String baz; // read-only (getter)

  int _weight;
  set weight(int value) {
    assert(weight >= 0);
    _weight = value;
  }
  int get weight => _weight
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example of it? It seems like you are saying correctly but i am not getting it properly!

Comment: An example of no getter/setter? I added some code but I don't know what you want to see.

Comment: person want to ask who to generate "getter and setter" automatically. 
not writing them one by one manually

Answer (score 26):

I didn't clearly understand your questions but check if this helps.

```
String _myValue = "Hello World";
```

Now press Comman+N in mac and select Getter and Setter.

[image]

[image]

Now that you can see the Getter and Setter generated for you.

```
String _myValue = "Hello World";

  String get myValue => _myValue;

  set myValue(String value) {
    _myValue = value;
  }
```

Ensure that you use "_" as a prefix for the private variables.

To understand getter and setter in dart follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzQkSwXkjgg) youtube video.

EDIT:

Noticing the higher votes for my answer, I'm responsible to clarify a few things here. As rightly mentioned by [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer), explicit getter/setter declarations are not necessary for Dart.

Comment: in previous updates of android studio getter and setter are not creating automatically in flutter..thats why i posted this question!

Comment: Is it working now? Are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes android studio starts generating automatically!

Comment: Does anyone know how to remove blank lines between getters while auto-formatting Dart code in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio Dart

I was also stuck on the same, I found out that we have to declare our private variable names with an underscore ( **_TestVariable** ).

Then use the shortcut **Alt + insert** (On Windows) to generate automatic Getters/Setters

```
class Books
{
  late int _id;

int get id => _id;

  set id(int value) {
    _id = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio:

1. Right click on the variable name on the line where you declare it.
2. Click on "Show Context Actions" or Option + Enter on Mac
3. Then click on "Encapsulate Field".